# How to produce two documents with one tex file?

Tags: compiling, tex-core, dvips, multiple-files, ps2pdf

I have given (it is already typeseted) two very similar projects: A catalog with exercises and solutions and a catalog with **only** short solutions for the exercises. Because of the use of the package `comment` both projects only differ by four lines of code (see the MWE) `\includecomment{exercise}` vs. `\excludecomment{exercise}`, `\includecomment{answer}` vs. `\excludecomment{answer}` and `\includecomment{shortQuestions}` vs. `\excludecomment{shortQuestions}`. Both projects have its own main file: `solutions.tex` for the full catalog and `shortSolutions.tex` for short solutions only. Both projects sharing one directory `exercises` with the files for exercises, let say `introduction.tex`, ... , `measurementTechnology.tex`, see the MWE. Each exercise file, for example `introduction.tex` contains with the environment `exercise` the exercise itself, the short solution with the environment `shortAnswer`, the full solution with environment `answer` and short questions for the current topic with the environment `shortQuestions`, see the MWE.

My task is to create **always** both documents with only one `tex` file. So one have to compile only one `tex` file, let say `solutions.tex` to get both documents. I found some information [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files/5265#5265), but I'am doing something wrong, because I receive only one file with the full catalog.

See my MWE: (**Attention!** It seems there is a conflict between the environment `filecontents` and the `comment` package, because of it my code below compiles only if there aren't blank spaces or tabs in front of `\begin{comment environment}` and `\end{comment environment}`. Even LaTeX comments with `%` after `\begin{comment environment}` and `\end{comment environment}` aren't allowed, see below.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               10pt,
               fleqn,
               twoside,
               onecolumn,
               openright,
               english
              ]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents*}{preamble.tex}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[babel = true]{microtype}
  \usepackage[
              locale = DE,
              per-mode = fraction,
              product-symbol = \cdot,
              product-units = single
             ]{siunitx}
  \usepackage{
              amsmath,
              amssymb,
              babel,
              booktabs,
              cancel,
              chemplants,
              comment,
              enumitem,
              graphicx,
              lscape,
              lmodern,
              mathtools,
              nicefrac,
              polynom,
              stanli,
              xurl
             }
  \usepackage[text]{esdiff}
  \usepackage[
              nooldvoltagedirection,
              european,
              cuteinductors
             ]{circuitikz}
  \usepackage[
              pdfstartview = FitB,
              bookmarksnumbered,
              colorlinks
             ]{hyperref}
  \title{Title for solutions}
  \author{Author Name}
\end{filecontents*}
\input{preamble}

\includecomment{exercise}
\includecomment{shortAnswer}
\includecomment{answer}
\includecomment{shortQuestions}

\begin{filecontents*}{exercises/introduction.tex}
  \begin{exercise}
    Text of the current exercise.
  \end{exercise}

  \begin{shortAnswer}
    Text of the idea for the solution or the final result.
  \end{shortAnswer}

  \begin{answer}
    Text of the step to step solution of the current exercise.
  \end{answer}

  \begin{shortQuestions}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Fist short question to the current subject.
      \item Second short question to the current subject.
      \item\ldots
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{shortQuestions}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{exercises/measurementTechnology.tex}
  \begin{exercise}
    Text of the current exercise.
  \end{exercise}

  \begin{shortAnswer}
    Text of the idea for the solution or the final result.
  \end{shortAnswer}

  \begin{answer}
    Text of the step to step solution of the current exercise.
  \end{answer}

  \begin{shortQuestions}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Fist short question to the current subject.
      \item Second short question to the current subject.
      \item\ldots
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{shortQuestions}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{content.tex}
  \frontmatter
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \cleardoublepage
  \mainmatter
  \part{Part 1}
    \chapter{Title 1}
      \input{exercises/introduction}
  \cleardoublepage
  \part{Part 2}
    \chapter{Title 1}
      \input{exercises/measurementTechnology}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{shortSolutions.tex}
  \documentclass[
                 a4paper,
                 10pt,
                 fleqn,
                 twoside,
                 onecolumn,
                 openright,
                 english,
                 ngerman
                ]{memoir}
  \input{preamble}
  \title{Title for short solutions}
  \excludecomment{exercise}
  \includecomment{shortAnswer}
  \excludecomment{answer}
  \excludecomment{shortQuestions}
  \begin{document}
    \input{content}
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \input{content}
  \immediate\write18{latex --shell-escape shortSolutions.tex}
\end{document}
```

I use `MikTeX` with `TeXnicCenter` to compile with `LaTeX -> DviPs -> ps2pdf` (I have to use it) and following profile settings:

`LaTeX`:

[image: TeXnicCenter 1]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe`

Arguments: `--enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"`

`DviPs` (PDF):

[image: TeXnicCenter 2]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\dvips.exe`

Arguments: `-P pdf -R0 "%bm.dvi"`

and `Ghostscript` (`ps2pdf`):

[image: TeXnicCenter 3]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\mgs.exe`

Arguments: `-sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%bm.pdf" -c save pop -f "%bm.ps"`

**For the line of code** `\immediate\write18{latex --shell-escape shortSolutions.tex}` the logfile says `runsystem(latex --shell-escape shortSolutions.tex)...executed.`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: So you do two compiles, with some kind of flag-variations? If so: don't see how you tell Latex which version you want. Or do you expect one compile creating two pdf's ?

Comment: @MS-SPO It's hard for me to be sure, because I have to keep scrolling past all the unneeded class options and packages, but I think compiling the main tex file is also supposed to trigger `\immediate\write18{latex --shell-escape shortSolutions.tex}` (next to last line) that isn't happening.  Su-47: does the log file say anything about that line?

Comment: Right. I also wonder where the flag-related environments are like `\begin{exercise} ... \end{exercise}`, which the comment package talks about.

Comment: @Teepeemm But that would require a second file `shortSolutions.tex`, wouldn't it? So is the idea to have two files but only directly compile one?

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691080/11604) solves your issue?

Comment: Using `filecontents` seems like cheating ;-)  All the old files will show up afterward.

Comment: Hello @John Kormylo! I use `filecontents` only here on `TeX.Stack Exchange`, because otherwise I don't have a possibility to use different files like I do on my machine. Therefore my code on my machine doesn't contain `filecontents` environments.

Comment: Hello @Fran! No, like I wrote in my unedited question my task is _...to create both documents with only one tex file._ See also my edited question.

Comment: Hello @Teepeemm! Thank you for your good comment! See my edited question.

Comment: Hello @MS-SPO! Thank you for your both clarifying comments! See my edited question!

Comment: Hello @cfr! Thank you for your excellent comment! You are right. See my edited question.

Comment: Note that allows the execution of arbitrary code via  \write18 and shell escape is a potential security hole. Compile two times after some minor modification of a single main file not as bad as it could seem, except t if you really need an unattended automatic generation of documents (which is not usually the case).

Comment: Why are you using different options for shell escape for the two compiles? If your compiler needs option A, presumably it wants A in both cases.

Comment: Hello @cfr! Thank for your comment! The logfile for the line of code `\immediate\write18{latex --enable-write18 shortSolutions.tex}` says again `runsystem(latex --enable-write18 shortSolutions.tex)...executed.`, but I'am receive only the full catalog as before.

Comment: Could you trim down your example?  `shortSolutions.tex` only needs to have `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} success \end{document}`, and your main document can just have the `\immediate\write18`.  And do you need to have `--enable-write18`?

Comment: Hello @Teepeemm! Thank you for your comment! It was the right hint! If I hardcode the `\immediate\write18` command with global paths and separate it into three parts for `LaTeX`, `DviPs` (PDF) and `Ghostscript` (`ps2pdf`) I get the desired result, see also my next comment. Now it would be great to do it without global paths. On the other hand if I think that my editor uses global paths to, then it is perhaps necessary. Any ideas? About `--enable-write18` I'am not sure, because I got the project with this flags. It is probably not needed. I have to test it.

Comment: 1. `LaTeX`: `\immediate\write18{D:/TeXnicCenter/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/latex.exe --enable-write18 shortSolutions.tex}`, 2. `DviPs` (PDF): `\immediate\write18{D:/TeXnicCenter/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/dvips.exe -P pdf -R0 shortSolutions.dvi}` and 3. `Ghostscript` (`ps2pdf`): `\immediate\write18{D:/TeXnicCenter/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/mgs.exe -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=shortSolutions.pdf -c save pop -f shortSolutions.ps}`.